# SPFx webpart with No Javascript Framework is it possible to style buttons to the Office UI Fabric to make them look like OOTB?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

In an SPFx webpart which has No Javascript Framework is it possible to style buttons and other elements to the Office UI Fabric to make them look like OOTB?
Thanks
P

```
 this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <div class="${ styles.customWebPart }">
          <div class="${ styles.basicListContainer }">
          <div class="${ styles.basicListTitle }">${this.properties.wpTitle}</div>
          <Button>click me please</Button>
          <Label>click me please</Label>
          <p> ${await this.getListData(filterValue)}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`;
```

Comment: Yes, install npm module `office-ui-fabric-react` & then you can use office ui/fluent ui controls in your web part.

Comment: Hi Ganesh I have the office-ui-fabric-react in my package.json .... I try to render the button and label (code in OP) but it doesn't look right. Thanks P